# How are scalars stored 'under the hood' in perl?

Tags: perl

The basic types in perl are different then most languages, with types being scalar, array, hash (but apparently not subroutines, &, which I guess are really just scalar references with syntactical sugar).  What is most odd about this is that the most common data types: int, boolean, char, string, all fall under the basic data type "scalar".  It seems that perl decides rather to treat a scalar as a string, boolean, or number based off of the operator that modifies it, implying the scalar itself is not actually defined as "int" or "String" when saved.

This makes me curious as to how these scalars are stored "under the hood", particularly in regards to it's effect on efficiency (yes I know scripting languages sacrifice efficiency for flexibility, but they still need to be as optimized as possible when flexibility concerns are not affected).  It's much easier for me to store the number 65535 (which takes two bytes) then the string "65535" which takes 6 bytes, as such recognizing that $val = 65535 is storing an int would allow me to use 1/3 the memory, in large arrays this could mean fewer cache hits as well.

It's not just limited to saving memory of course.  There are times when I can offer more significant optimizations if I know what type of scalar to expect.  For instance if I have a hash using very large integers as keys it would be far faster to look up a value if I recognizing the keys as ints, allowing a simply modulo for creating my hash key, then if I have to run more complex hashing logic on a string that has 3 times the bytes.

So I'm wondering how perl handles these scalars under the hood.  Does it store every value as a string, sacrificing the extra memory and cpu cost of constant converting string to int in the case that a scalar is always used as an int?  Or does it have some logic for inference the type of scalar used to determine how to save and manipulate it?

Edit:

TJD linked to perlguts, which answers half my question.  A scalar is actually stored as string, int (signed, unsigned, double) or pointer.  I'm not too surprised, I had mostly expected this behavior to occur under the hood, though it's interesting to see the exact types.  I'm leaving this question open though because perlguts is actually to low level.  Other then telling me that 5 data types exist it doesn't specify how perl works to alternate between them, ie how perl decides which SV type to use when a scalar is saved and how it knows when/how to cast.

Comment: [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html)

Comment: The `perlguts` itself contains: _This document attempts to describe how to use the Perl API, as well as to provide **some** info on the basic workings of the Perl core. **It is far from complete and probably contains many errors.** Please refer any questions or comments to the author below._ - This question is fairly legal and should be answered more nicely as one world comment.

Comment: [perlguts illustrated](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.49/index.html)

Comment: Re. your edit: each operator handles its operands differently. Once you've read through perlguts and [illguts](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.49/index.html), take a look at some of the opcodes in pp_hot.c in the Perl source. pp_add is interesting because it tries to do integer addition if possible and so adds an integer representation to each operand. The comments are instructive even if you can't follow the code: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/pp_hot.c#L641. Also check out pp_print and pp_concat.

Comment: Re: How Perl "alternates between them [types]", the camel book gives a succinct explanation on page 5: "Various operators expect certain kinds of values as parameters, so we will speak of those operators as "providing" or "supplying" a scalar context to those parameters. Sometimes we'll be more specific, and say it supplies a numeric context, a string context, or a Boolean context...". The implication being that operators are NOT overloaded and the expected types can be uniquely determined from *them*.

Comment: @JeffY with certain exceptions like the bitwise operators, that have one mode of operation of both operands are just strings and another if either is a stored as a number (which can happen from just using it in a numeric context) (e.g. "0"^"0" is "\0" but 0^0 is 0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are actually a number of types of scalars. A scalar of type `SVt_IV` can hold undef, a signed integer (`IV`) or an unsigned integer (`UV`). One of type `SVt_PVIV` can also hold a string<sup>[1]</sup>. Scalars are silently upgraded from one type to another as needed<sup>[2]</sup>. The `TYPE` field indicates the type of a scalar. In fact, arrays (`SVt_AV`) and hashes (`SVt_HV`) are really just types of scalars.

While the type of a scalar indicates what the scalar *can* contain, flags are used to indicate what a scalar *does* contain. This is stored in the `FLAGS` field. `SVf_IOK` signals that a scalar contains a signed integer, while `SVf_POK` indicates it contains a string<sup>[3]</sup>.

[Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Peek)'s `Dump` is a great tool for looking at the internals of scalars. (The constant prefixes `SVt_` and `SVf_` are omitted by `Dump`.)

```
$ perl -e'
   use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
   my $x = 123;
   Dump($x);
   $x = "456";
   Dump($x);
   $x + 0;
   Dump($x);
'
SV = IV(0x25f0d20) at 0x25f0d30       <-- SvTYPE(sv) == SVt_IV, so it can contain an IV.
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)                  <-- IOK: Contains an IV.
  IV = 123                            <-- The contained signed integer (IV).

SV = PVIV(0x25f5ce0) at 0x25f0d30     <-- The SV has been upgraded to SVt_PVIV
  REFCNT = 1                              so it can also contain a string now.
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)            <-- POK: Contains a string (but no IV since !IOK).
  IV = 123                            <-- Meaningless without IOK.
  PV = 0x25f9310 "456"\0              <-- The contained string.
  CUR = 3                             <-- Number of bytes used by PV (not incl \0).
  LEN = 10                            <-- Number of bytes allocated for PV.
  COW_REFCNT = 1

SV = PVIV(0x25f5ce0) at 0x25f0d30
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pPOK)   <-- Now contains both a string (POK) and an IV (IOK).
  IV = 456                            <-- This will be used in numerical contexts.
  PV = 0x25f9310 "456"\0              <-- This will be used in string contexts.
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
```

[illguts](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/) documents the internal format of variables quite thoroughly, but [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) might be a better place to start.

If you start writing XS code, keep in mind it's usually a bad idea to check what a scalar contains. Instead, you should request what should have been provided (e.g. using `SvIV` or `SvPVutf8`). Perl will automatically convert the value to the requested type (and warn if appropriate). API calls are documented in [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html).

---

1. In fact, it can hold a string an either a signed integer or an unsigned integer at the same time.
2. All scalars (including arrays and hashes, excluding one type of scalar that can only hold undef) have two memory blocks at their base. Pointers to the scalar point to its *head*, which contains the `TYPE` field and a pointer to the *body*. Upgrading a scalar replaces the body of the scalar. That way, pointers to the scalar aren't invalidated by an upgrade.
3. An undef variable is one without any uppercase `OK` flags set.

Answer (score 12):

The formats used by Perl for data storage are documented in the [`perlguts`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) perldoc.

In short, though, a Perl scalar is stored as a `SV` structure containing one of a number of different types, such as an `int`, a `double`, a `char *`, or a pointer to another scalar. (These types are stored as a C `union`, so only one of them will be present at a time; the SV contains flags indicating which type is used.)

(With regard to hash keys, there's an important gotcha to note there: *hash keys are always strings, and are always stored as strings*. They're stored in a different type from other scalars.)

The Perl API includes a number of functions which can be used to access the value of a scalar as a desired C type. For example, `SvIV()` can be used to return the integer value of a SV: if the SV contains an `int`, that value is returned directly; if the SV contains another type, it's coerced to an integer as appropriate. These functions are used throughout the Perl interpreter for type conversions. However, there is no automatic inference of types on output; functions which operate on strings will always return a `PV` (string) scalar, for instance, regardless of whether the string "looks like" a number or not.

If you're curious what a given scalar looks like internally, you can use the [`Devel::Peek`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Peek) module to dump its contents.

Answer (score 6):

Others have addressed the "how are scalars stored" part of your question, so I'll skip that.  With regard to how Perl decides which representation of a value to use and when to convert between them, the answer is it depends on which operators are applied to the scalar.  For example, given this code:

```
my $score = 0;
```

The scalar `$score` will be initialised with an integer value.  But then when this line of code is run:

```
say "Your score is $score";
```

The double quote operator means that Perl will need a string representation of the value.  So the conversion from integer to string will take place as part of the process of assembling the string argument to the `say` function.  Interestingly, after the stringification of `$score`, the underlying representation of the scalar will now include **both** an integer **and** a string representation, allowing subsequent operations to directly grab the relevant value without having to convert again.  If a numeric operator is then applied to the string (e.g.: `$score++`) then the numeric part will be updated and the (now invalid) string part will be discarded.

This is the reason why Perl operators tend to come in two flavours.  For example comparing values of numbers is done with `<`, `==`, `>` while performing the same comparisons with strings would be done with `lt`, `eq`, `gt`.  Perl will coerce the value of the scalar(s) to the type which matches the operator.  This is why the `+` operator does numeric addition in Perl but a separate operator `.` is needed to do string concatenation: `+` will coerce its arguments to numeric values and `.` will coerce to strings.

There are some operators that will work with both numeric and string values but which perform a different operation depending on the type of value. For example:

```
$score = 0;
say ++$score;       # 1
say ++$score;       # 2
say ++$score;       # 3

$score = 'aaa';
say ++$score;       # 'aaa'
say ++$score;       # 'aab'
say ++$score;       # 'aac'
```

With regard to questions of efficiency (and bearing in mind standard disclaimers about premature optimisation etc).  Consider this code which reads a file containing one integer per line, each integer is validated to check it is exactly 8 digits long and the valid ones are stored in an array:

```
my @numbers;
while(<$fh>) {
    if(/^(\d{8})$/) {
        push @numbers, $1;
    }
}
```

Any data read from a file will initially come to us as a string.  The regex used to validate the data will also require a string value in `$_`.  So the result is that our array `@numbers` will contain a list of strings.  However, if further uses of the values will be solely in a numeric context, we could use this micro-optimisation to ensure that the array contained only numeric values:

```
push @numbers, 0 + $1;
```

In my tests with a file of 10,000 lines, populating `@numbers` with strings used nearly three times as much memory as populating with integer values.  However as with most benchmarks, this has little relevance to normal day-to-day coding in Perl.  You'd only need to worry about that in situations where you a) had performance or memory issues and b) were working with a large number of values.

It's worth pointing out that some of this behaviour is common to other dynamic languages (e.g.: Javascript will silently coerce numeric values to strings).

Comment: Tangential, but `0 + $foo` has a more practical usage when you're serializing data (e.g. with [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#PERL---JSON)).